# If the image file size is less than 50 kb, there is a 5 second delay in refresh the page

Tags: javascript, opencv

The goal is to apply a bounding box to the cam image and print it on the web.

python

```
cv.imwrite("rgb.jpg",rgb_img,[int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY),95]) //image size 53 kb
```

javascript

```
function ref() {
    var url = "rgb.jpg";
    fetch(url, {cache: 'reload', mode: 'no-cors'})
    $('#refimg').attr('src',url);
    timerID = setTimeout("ref()", 1000);
}
```

html

```
<img style="-webkit-user-select: none;" width="300" height="200" id="refimg" alt="loading..." />
```

This results in the latest image capture every second, but the size is large, causing problems such as blinking and truncated image.

So I reduced the image size.

```
cv.imwrite("rgb.jpg",rgb_img,[int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY),94]) //image size 48 kb
```

However, when the image size is reduced to less than 50kb, the screen is updated every 5 seconds in the same JavaScript code.

```
cv.imwrite("rgb.webp",rgb_img,[int(cv2.IMWRITE_WEBP_QUALITY),80]) //image size 10 kb
```

I've tried webp, png, and so on, but the moment it goes below 50kb, same happens.

Comment: Have you check that your image is really read every second ? Are you sur that a "cache system" in your browser doesn't block your reload even you set cache : reload ? (With json, I experiment trouble like this, even I have activte all "cache: reload" option).

Comment: Of course. The cam has a timestamp. The image shows up to seconds.